# Strange behavior of fullscreen mode on Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-7.0-nougat, android-fullscreen

I have an application which will show fullscreen without problem on Android 4-6. But once test on Android 7.0, although the navigation and status bar are hide, the navigation bar position seems still occupied by a white bar. My application cannot automatically resize to occupy that space.

```
mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

I use the above code to do the fullscreen. Please advise. Thanks.